# How to change button on pressed color in multiple buttons React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have 3 buttons in my react native app. When user clicks button 1 I need to change it color to orange. But other buttons should have the default color (grey). If user clicks the button 3 next time, color should change to orange ,but that 1st button color should reset to default. I'm totally new to react native and this is what I tried. But it applies for all buttons. I know if I can have multiple states with unique Id , it can be done. But I don't know the method.

```
<Text style={ styles.switchButtonsTitle }>Choose Type of User</Text>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={(userType) =>
    this.selectionOnPress("BASIC")} >
    <Text style={_style}>
        <Text style={styles.switchButtonsText}>BASIC</Text>
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>


<TouchableOpacity onPress={(userType) =>
    this.selectionOnPress("INTERMEDIATE")}>
    <Text style={_style}>
        <Text style={styles.switchButtonsText}>INTERMEDIATE</Text>
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={(userType) =>
    this.selectionOnPress("ADVANCED")}>
    <Text style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor}}>
        <Text style={styles.switchButtonsText}>ADVANCED</Text>
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

selectionOnPress

```
selectionOnPress(userType) {
    this.setState({
        onClicked: true
    });
}
```

props

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        onClicked: false
    }
    this.selectionOnPress = this.selectionOnPress.bind(this)
}
```

render(not adding the all codes, only added the useful codes for this post)

```
render() {
    var _style;
    if (this.state.onClicked) { // clicked button style
        _style = {
            backgroundColor: "red"
        }
    }
    else { // default button style
        _style = {
            backgroundColor: "blue"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I make some modification on your code

```
 export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedButton: null };
    this.selectionOnPress = this.selectionOnPress.bind(this);
}

selectionOnPress(userType) {
    this.setState({ selectedButton: userType });
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.switchButtonsTitle}>
                Choose Type of User
            </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.selectionOnPress("BASIC")}
            >
                <Text
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor:
                            this.state.selectedButton === "BASIC"
                                ? "red"
                                : "grey"
                    }}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.switchButtonsText}>BASIC</Text>
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.selectionOnPress("INTERMEDIATE")}
            >
                <Text
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor:
                            this.state.selectedButton === "INTERMEDIATE"
                                ? "red"
                                : "grey"
                    }}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.switchButtonsText}>
                        INTERMEDIATE
                    </Text>
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.selectionOnPress("ADVANCED")}
            >
                <Text
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor:
                            this.state.selectedButton === "ADVANCED"
                                ? "red"
                                : "grey"
                    }}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.switchButtonsText}>
                        INTERMEDIATE
                    </Text>
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
}


... don't forget to define your styles
```

Comment: Hi Ali, Thanks a lot for the support.  I need to call selectionOnPress function also. Could you please help me how do I call this in here?

Comment: learned a lot from you. This answer will be helpful for all react native newbies..Thanks bro

Comment: I need to add text color to this code like ( <Text style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.selectedButton === "ADVANCED" ? 'red' : 'grey' }}>) backgroundColor , can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

First i recommend you to create a button component.
https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/organizing-a-react-native-project-9514dfadaa0

a easy way to do it is creating a state for each button like this

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={
        (userType) => this.selectionOnPress("BASIC");
        this.setState({backgroundColor1: this.state.backgroundColor1 == 'grey'? 'orange' : 'grey'});
}>
    <Text style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor1}}>
        <Text style={styles.switchButtonsText}>BASIC</Text> 
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={
    (userType) => this.selectionOnPress("INTERMEDIATE");
    this.setState({backgroundColor2: this.state.backgroundColor2 == 'grey'? 'orange' : 'grey'});
}>
    <Text style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor2}>
        <Text style={styles.switchButtonsText}>INTERMEDIATE</Text> 
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={
    (userType) => this.selectionOnPress("ADVANCED");
    this.setState({backgroundColor3: this.state.backgroundColor3 == 'grey'? 'orange' : 'grey', backgroundColor1: 'grey'});
}>
    <Text style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor}}>
        <Text style={styles.switchButtonsText}>ADVANCED</Text> 
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplified example:

```
//jsx
// asign default class name to your buttons with desired default color,
// onclick change said class to active css class which will have different background color
   <div>
    <button onClick={this.handleClick} className='btn-default'>basic</button>
    <button onClick={this.handleClick} className='btn-default'>intermediate</button>
    <button onClick={this.handleClick} className='btn-default'>advance</button>
  </div>

//js
// this method select parent element of your button which is also parent
// element for other buttons and then gets all other buttons in button 
// variable via children property
  handleClick(event) {
    const buttons = event.target.parentElement.children;
    for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        //here you set all buttons to default color
        buttons[i].classList.add('btn-default');
        buttons[i].classList.remove('btn-active');
    }
    //here you add active class(color) to button you originally clicked
    event.target.classList.add('btn-active');
  }

  //css

.btn-default {
   background-color: grey;
 }

.btn-active {
   background-color: orange;
 }
```

Comment: Question is for react native