# React Native, Unexpected Keyword "This"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Why I have an red error marks the dot after This Keyword? it says (Unexpected Keyword "This")

```
    render() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.selectionOnPress({this.props.detail.country})}>
            <Text style={[styles.btnSV, {
                backgroundColor:
                    this.state.selectedButton === {this.props.detail.country} ? "red" : "grey"
            }]}>
                <Text style={styles.btnSV}>{this.props.detail.country}</Text>
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

    );
}}
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jNNB.jpg)

Comment: What does it say when you hover over it?

Comment: @Nathan it says (Unexpected Keyword "This")

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
render() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.selectionOnPress(this.props.detail.country)}>
            <Text style={[styles.btnSV, {
                backgroundColor:
                    this.state.selectedButton === this.props.detail.country ? "red" : "grey"
            }]}>
                <Text style={styles.btnSV}>{this.props.detail.country}</Text>
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

    );
}}
```

I basically removed surrounding curly brackets from 1st and 2nd instances of `this.props.detail.country`
Within JS, these curly brackets are object notation and are missing property names.
3rd instance is JSX template variable.

Comment: It doesn't toggling between red and grey like before.

Comment: Then my guess is that selectionOnPress() update state.selectedButton? If the initial value for state.selectedButton is falsy, first tap would set it to props.detail.country and change button background to red. Now what is suppose to happen if you tap it again? And is there another button that sets state.selectedButton to different value?

Comment: constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { selectedButton: null };
        this.selectionOnPress = this.selectionOnPress.bind(this);
    }

    selectionOnPress(userType) {
        this.setState({ selectedButton: userType });
    }

Comment: Then, within `selectionOnPress()`, do this: `this.setState(preState => prevState.selectedButton === userType ? null : userType)` This will toggle between null and the value when tapping on same button and should toggle between red and grey button.

Comment: It gives me only Grey color even if I clicked twice no more Red color.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48444567/13854515 This solution does not work.

Comment: `this.setState(prevState => prevState.selectedButton === userType ? { selectedButton: null } : { selectedButton: userType})`

Comment: It works now, but with multi-selection buttons. How can I achieve one single button to be highlighted each time?Which means if I clicked the New button it turns to Red & the Previous one turns to Grey and so on.

Comment: So if you want something like radio button group where choosing one will deselect other, you just give other buttons its own prop value but use same state. Only most recently tapped button will have red and others grey.